# How can I bulk add CiviVolunteer projects?

Tags: civivolunteer

I will be running events 5 days a week for a couple of weeks every month.  I need to schedule them individually.  It seems like the best way to do this is to create a project for each day.  Is that correct?  If so, how do I create them in bulk?  Maybe a Scheduled Job that runs an API command once a day?  Is there something more end-user friendly?

Comment: Won't civi event recurring help?

Comment: @PradeepNayak I'll investigate, but these aren't events - it's basically office help (though remote right now).